# R package Installation failed: cannot change working directory

Tags: r, git, failed-installation, working-directory, setwd

I get the following error message when trying to install package "rChart" in R:

```
**Installation failed: cannot change working directory**
```

Somebody advised me to install "Rcpp" before "rChart". So I did so.
However, it is still same before.

```
> install_github("saurfang/rCharts", ref = "utf8-writelines")
Downloading GitHub repo saurfang/rCharts@utf8-writelines
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/saurfang/rCharts/zipball/utf8-writelines
Installing rCharts
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCYR9NS/devtools246c28fe1bc3/saurfang-rCharts-e0106ed"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

**Installation failed: cannot change working directory**
```